# mysql connection from VM to host

Tags: mysql, networking, ssh

Host:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- 192.168.1.4
- mysql database with: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO grails@'192.168.122.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'grails';

VM :

- Centos 6.6
- 192.168.122.111

Problem:
Application (grails) can't see mysql database located on host machine.

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.122.11/grails?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

I can

- ping between 'machines'.
- log with ssh from host to vm and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flushing the privileges
login as root and use MySQL; Database, something to do with the grant privilege

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

remove the old user entry for that user and do a direct INSERT for the user with the domain into **user** table.
insert into user (....) values (....)

Comment: thanks, I had a little mess with users. After cleaning and this command it's ok

Answer (score 1):

permission should be as per below-

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO grails@'192.168.122.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'grails';
or
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO grails@'192.168.122.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'grails';
```

If your permissions are ok, then go to 192.168.122.111 machine and try to connect db server from here by below command-

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.4 -ugrails -pgrails
```

If not able from here also then you need to check other things like iptables related firewall setting, port 3306 is open or not etc.

Comment: That command was properly, but something went wrong with coping. I turned off all firewalls  but still cant connect with mysql -h 192.168.1.4 -ugrails -pgrails

Comment: go db server 192.168.1.4 and use command: mysql -uroot -p<password> and check if you are able to connect mysql prompt